# WebStorm not recognising index.ts files in imports

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, import, webpack, webstorm

I have a project setup which is using Webpack. I have a few aliases for different directories:

```
alias {
    shared/common: path.join(__dirname, 'src/main/js/publish/shared/common')
    app/common: path.join(__dirname, 'src/main/js/publish/app/common')
}
```

In some files I would like to import different modules from a single [barrel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#B):

```
import { Comp1, Comp5, Comp7 } from 'shared/common/components';
```

In order to make that work, inside `shared/common/components` I created the barrel `index.ts` file:

```
import { Comp1 } from '.comp1/comp1.comp';
import { Comp2 } from '.comp2/comp2.comp';
import { Comp3 } from '.comp3/comp3.comp';
....
import { CompN } from '.compN/compN.comp';

export {
    Comp1,
    Comp2,
    Comp3,
    ...
    CompN
}
```

Although this compiles fine, WebStorm displays an error in the first import saying that it cannot resolve all those symbols.

I tried to mark `src/main/js/publish` as Resource Root, as that's the directory which contains `shared` and `app`, but still doesn't work.

It works fine if I change the import to:

```
import { Comp1, Comp5, Comp7 } from 'shared/common/components/index.ts';
```

Is there any way to make WebStorm recognise those index.ts files without actually writing them in the imports?

Comment: which ide version do you use?

Comment: @anstarovoyt Webstorm 11.0.4

Comment: the problem should be fixed in WS2016.1.3 and WS2016.2

Comment: @anstarovoyt True. It would be nice if there's any other solution, but I check that out with someone else that has updated it and it worked. You can create an answer if you want to (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anstarovoyt pointed out in his comment, the problem was fixed after updating to `WS2016.2`.

So it seems that the only two options are either update your WebStorm or keep writing the extension in the imports:

```
import { Comp1, Comp5, Comp7 } from 'shared/common/components/index.ts';
```